# How to clear screen in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, screen

I used to `#include <conio.h>` then `clrscr ()` to clear the screen in `C`.

`system("cls")` is the same. I tried that but it's not working in `Xcode`.

So how do you clear the screen in `Xcode`?

Please help

Comment: perhaps you want to use a library like `ncurses` or `curses`

Comment: There is no "screen" in C or in XCode.

Comment: system("clear") help in code:blocks but it ddnt work in xcode

Answer (score 2):

system("clear") should work on terminal, may not in xcode.

Check post #10 in this thread -> http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=173777

(This would be a comment but I don't have reputation yet)